# Delete Batch is not commited

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have such a batch delete:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @rows INT, @count INT, @message VARCHAR(100);
SET @rows = 1;
SET @count = 0;
WHILE @rows > 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
delete top(100000) from Table whete T1='HU'
    SET @rows = @@ROWCOUNT;

 SET @count = @count + @rows
  RAISERROR('COUNT %d', 0, 1, @count) WITH NOWAIT
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

But this query is not commited, After I try to close the window (session) I am asked If I would like to commit the transaction.

Is my query wrong?

Comment: It's probably not commited because you are raising an error just before the commit...

Comment: If I delete raiserror, still query doesnt commit the transaction

Comment: @ZoharPeled - `RAISERROR` with a *severity* of less than 11 is basically like `printf`.

Comment: btw, why do think you need an explicit transaction if you are beginning and commiting it inside the loop, you don't need it at all.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks. I remembered something about severity but was too lazy to look it up...

Comment: Just remove the explicit transaction and the raiserror. Those are nothing other than noise in here. And just set @rows to @@rowcount, no need to keep a cumulative count.

Comment: @SeanLange can you explain me, after removing these statements, why my Batch Delete works?

Comment: Because the transaction is pointless. There is an implicit transaction on any DML statement so adding an explicit one here is just extra code with zero benefit. And the raiserror is just more code that is not providing any actual benefit. But I don't see how you would receive the transaction message you state with only the code posted here.

Comment: Are you doing all of this work in a single query window? Which started possibly with some non-working code that you've had to make a few attempts to get right? I've seen people leak transactions from previous attempts where the problem is no longer evident in the code they're running *now*. You'll effectively be running all of your current transactions as "nested" transactions inside the leaked one(s). Add `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT` at the top of your query and confirm the number is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @rows INT, @count INT, @message VARCHAR(100);
SET @rows = 1;
SET @count = 0;
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    WHILE @rows > 0
    BEGIN
    delete top(100000) from Table whete T1='HU'
        SET @rows = @@ROWCOUNT;

     SET @count = @count + @rows
      RAISERROR('COUNT %d', 0, 1, @count) WITH NOWAIT
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

-------------For example

```
Declare @tbl Table(
CustomerID  INT ,
CustomerName         VARCHAR(100),
AccreditationNumber  VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1272,'Bree','Gold')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1272,'Bree','Gold')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1272,'Bree','Gold')

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1272,'Anneke','silver')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1272,'Anneke','silver')

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @rows INT, @count INT, @message VARCHAR(100);
SET @rows = 1;
SET @count = 0;
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    WHILE @rows > 0
    BEGIN
    delete top(1) from @tbl where CustomerID=1272
        SET @rows = @@ROWCOUNT;

     SET @count = @count + @rows
      RAISERROR('COUNT %d', 0, 1, @count) WITH NOWAIT
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

Comment: I have test it, but still the same problem

Comment: please comment those lines                                                                                   
    SET count = count + rows
      RAISERROR('COUNT %d', 0, 1, @count) WITH NOWAIT

Comment: And replace whete to where

Comment: also check example in answer.